# PS - "MethodException: Cannot find an overload" - cutom class exceptions

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a custom class to create a custom PSObject ready to be filled and converted to a JSON file to be used as a body API request

Here's my goal :

- Instantiate my custom class to initialize my custom object
- Use different methods (here AddExtensions) to fill this object

This method's goal is to populate an array of strings, and some hard-coded values

the class looks like this

```
class allowlist {
[object] $Applications
[object] $Certificates
[object] $webdomains
[object] $ips_hosts
[object] $Extensions
[object] $windows
# Setting up the PSCustomObject structure from the JSON example : https://pastebin.com/FaKYpgw3
# TODO finish obj structure
allowlist() {
    $this.applications = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
    $this.Certificates = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
    $this.webdomains = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
    $this.ips_hosts = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
    $this.extensions = [System.Collections.Hashtable]::new()# TODO Extensions obj be hashtable. Converting to JSON will not be incorrect format (list instead of k/v pair)
    $this.windows = [PSCustomObject]@{
        files       = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
        directories = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
    }
}
#Method to add EXTENSIONS tab to the main obj
[void] AddExtensions(
    [array] $name
    # hardcoded values
    # [bool] $scheduled,
    # [string] $features
) {
    $this.extensions.add([PSCustomObject]@{
            names     = $name
            scheduled = $true
            features  = "AUTO_PROTECT"
        })
}
```

My code runs like this

```
    # Get Object from AllowList Class
    $obj_policy_excel = [allowlist]::new()
    ...
    # Add Extensions
    $obj_policy_excel.AddExtensions($Extensions.extensions)
```

my **$extensions** object is just an array of strings

```
PS C:\Project> $Extensions

extensions
----------
ade
adp
ldb
```

When I'm trying to use the Method, I have the following error :

```
PS C:\Project> $obj_policy_excel.AddExtensions($Extensions.extensions)

MethodException: Cannot find an overload for "add" and the argument count: "1".
```

There is a "Add" Method in the Hashtable object, so I don't understand the error. If I switch the Hashtable by a [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]] it works, but I specifically need a key/value pair for my later Json conversion.

**UPDATE**

The goal is to have object converted in JSON that looks like this at the end :

```
"extensions": {
        "names": [
            "txt",
            "exe",
            "doc"
        ],
        "scheduled": true,
        "features": [
            "AUTO_PROTECT"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Your class is missing a chunk of it's definition. Please format your code and add those missing pieces

Comment: As for the error, `AddExtensions` method is taking an array as argument yet you're feeding it a string: `"$Extensions.extensions"` why are the double quotes there?

Comment: Sorry didn't want to post the whole class as it's huge. Rearranged it. I missed up the formatting with the post, apologies. Regarding the double quotes, I tried with and without as I wasn't sure but I get the same

Comment: @Douda you need to supply a _key_ when you add entries to a hashtable, eg.: `$this.extensions.add('KeyGoesHere', [pscustomobject]@{...})`

Comment: Looking at your Json, I think you should define your `Extensions` property as a `PSCustomObject` which's `names` and `features` properties would be a `List<T>`. Mathias's comment would be solving the current error but I'm not sure that's what you actually want

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I'd expect the extension name to be used as key: `add($name, ...)`, but only OP can say :)

Comment: Thanks both of you. You're pointing me to the right direction. I'll rework the method to with the key/value pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing specifically on how might be a better way to approach it, looking at your [Json](https://pastebin.com/FaKYpgw3) there are 2 appearances of `Extensions` property and they both have the same structure. In this case you could break the problem into small pieces, create an `Extensions` class that has this structure and then and then have your main class have this new type as it's property (I've removed the not relevant pieces of your code for the sake of focusing on this specific problem):

```
class Extensions {
    [Collections.Generic.List[string]] $names = [Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
    [bool] $scheduled
    [Collections.Generic.List[string]] $features = [Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
}

class allowlist {
    [Extensions] $Extensions

    [void] AddExtensions([Extensions] $Extension) {
        $this.Extensions = $Extension
    }
}

$allowList = [allowlist]::new()
$allowList.AddExtensions(@{
    names     = 'pdf'
    scheduled = $true
    features  = 'AUTO_PROTECT'
})

$allowList | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Thanks santiago. As mentioned to Mathias, I was reworking basically what you did, just not as clean :)

Comment: @Douda I'm glad to help :) I see this question relates to the previous one. You're on the right path

Comment: FYI, not related, but you just showed me how to call a call from a class. I was looking to break that down in smaller chunks but didn't find the correct way. again thank you !

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to supply a *key* associated with each value when adding new entries to a hashtable. Assuming you want to index the extensions by "extension name", you could do something like:

```
class AllowList {

    # ...

    [void]
    AddExtensions([array] $extensionNames)
    {
        foreach($name in $extensionNames) {
            $this.Extensions.Add($name, [PSCustomObject]@{
                names     = $name
                scheduled = $true
                features  = "AUTO_PROTECT"
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You guys are so fast ! Thank you ! I've reworked the class as mentioned by Santiago but I'm taking your advise into account. Learning every day